How to implement unmodified shortcut keys in WPF?
I have a WPF app that consists of a main view ("viewA"), which in turn contains a couple of ContentPresenters used to display child views (user controls) - "viewB" & "viewC". All three views contain a variety of controls data grids, listboxes, charts, textboxes, etc.
The customer wants to use keyboard shortcuts to perform various tasks, for example pressing "G" might toggle the display of grid lines on a chart control that resides in "viewB". Another "must have" is to use the cursor keys to scroll a datagrid in "viewA" (I realise the WPF DG has something similar built-in, but we need a more sophisticated solution which isn't relevant to this question).
I've always managed to dodge working with any form of keyboard shortcut, so I'm now struggling to find a suitable solution. Control focus seems to be the secret here, but this seems to be a minefield in its own right, plus I feel that a user shouldn't have to click a control to give it focus before a particular shortcut key to work (for example clicking the chart control in viewB before key 'G' will work).
I naively implemented a "global" PreviewKeyDown event handler on the main view (viewA), to handle the shortcuts, before realising that if the user is (say) typing into a TextBox in any of the views and types a letter 'G' (or cursor left/right) then the corresponding shortcut action will also be triggered!
Using "unmodified" shortcut keys clearly isn't viable, unless it can be done at a more "local" control level, so should I be including a modifier key (e.g. Alt+G or Ctrl+G) on all shortcuts? One snag is that I'm rewriting a very old Winforms app where unmodified shortcuts are used a lot, so I can imagine users complaining if these aren't available in the WPF version. Also, pressing a modified shortcut typically requires two hands, which I can see our users disliking.
If modified keys are the only viable option then what is the recommended solution? Can I continue to use my "global" PreviewKeyDown event handler or is there a more elegant WPF approach? (Also note the app has no main menu in which keyboard gestures could be added).

Focus is a pain in WPF. The hotkeys are implemented using CommandBindings in WPF. I recall I had to merge those used in sub-view with ones from main window. I think it's possible to make with reusable behavior, so adding just one line to any sub-view is required.

The global keyboard event hanlder may be a viable option, because hotkey may call methods of running models. With MVVM in mind this can be a cool option if you want to have hotkeys working even if view is not displayed.

If you really need to implement a shortcut key without modifier keys, just do it at a more "local" control level. If a TextBox has the focus, disable your shortcut keys.
